# Efficiently post-changing the object of iteration

Tags: python, loops, optimization

I have a `stack` - an array of arrays of `elements` (initially, of the form `[[element]]`), a `queue` - an array of `element` and a function `func` mapping pair `(element1, element2)` to `resulting_element`. I'm trying to process `stack` and `queue` as follows

```
for new_element in queue:                                   #first loop
    stack_copy = [list(array) for array in stack]
    stack[0].append(new_element)
    for (index, array) in enumerate(stack_copy):            #second loop
        for element in array:                               #third loop
            resulting_element = func(element, new_element)
            try:
                stack[i+1].append(resulting_element)
            except:
                stack.append(list())
                stack[i+1].append(resulting_element)
```

So basically I want `new_element` to be inserted into `stack[0]` and`resulting_element` to be inserted into `stack[index+1]` (does not matter on which position) but only on next iteration of the first loop. The problem is that as we iterating inner loops, we obtain multiple `resulting_elements`. I tried that to create a temporary variable `stack_copy`, so that we iterated on "fixed" object but this seems to be very inefficient. I'm looking for the way to make this procedure work faster. I was thinking to some way to rewrite stack as a generator, which could be modified while it being iterated.
Essentially, the content of two inner loops should remain unchanged.

Comment: If the answer you have is not sufficient, consider making [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This should be reasonably efficient:

```py
for new_element in queue:
    additions = [[new_element]]
    additions.extend([func(element, new_element) for element in array]
                     for array in stack)
    for array, addition in zip(stack, additions):
        array += addition
    stack.append(additions[-1])
```

It's still creating some temporary lists but I don't think this is something you should be too worried about as long as the remaining code patterns are reasonably fast; and these should be